# Custom TensorflowJS model (exported from GCP AutoML) not running in HTML deployment

Tags: html, google-cloud-platform, object-detection, tensorflow.js, automl

I trained a custom object detection model using Google Cloud AutoML and exported the model as a TensorflowJS package.
However, when I try running the model using the HTML deployment example they have here https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs/tensorflow-js-tutorial?hl=en_US, it does not seem to work.

My tensorflowjs package from the export (model.json, dict.txt, group1-shard1of3,group1-shard2of3, group1-shard3of3)
are in the same directory as the index.html. I also have an index2.html. In index.html I use the same
imports for tfjs and tfjs-automl as the example here. In the index2.html I use CDN sources for tfjs and tfjs-automl.

The create web app example I followed is : https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/master/tfjs-automl/code_snippets/object_detection.html

My repo with my custom object detection model is: https://github.com/mmmwembe/automl-tensorflowjs.git including the tensorflowjs model package and the test-images.

My Index.html file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Cards AutoML Model - TensorflowJS</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@tensorflow/tfjs"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@tensorflow/tfjs-automl"></script>
<img id="test-image" src="test-images/test-image-01.jpg">

<script>
async function run() {

  const model = await tf.automl.loadObjectDetection('model.json');
  const img = document.getElementById('test-image');
  const options = {score: 0.5, iou: 0.5, topk: 20};
  const predictions = await model.detect(img, options);
  // [END load_and_run_model]
  console.log(predictions);

  // Show the resulting object on the page.
  const pre = document.createElement('pre');
  pre.textContent = JSON.stringify(predictions, null, 2);
  document.body.append(pre);

}

run();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

What am I missing here?...I've run this with Chrome browser using Live Server in vscode editor as well as with nodejs using http-server -p 8000

Comment: Can you run it and share if any error messages in the console of the web browser? (Press F12 and select console) or link me to the live webpage so I can check.